# Regra de htaccess para adicionar https

Tags: htaccess

Estou tentando criar uma regra dentro do meu htaccess para que seja adicionada a url o HTTPS. Acontece que isso deve acontecer apenas para um domínio especifico, como tratar isso em um rewritecond http_host?

exemplo:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} palavraChave
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

seria possível?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^suaurl\.com.br [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^suaurl\.com.br [NC]
e se tiver mais coisas depois do com.br?

Answer (score 1):

Conheço dois métodos:

**Importante**: Não force o uso de HTTPS se seu site não possuir certificado SSL.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Ou

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 /*porta que utiliza*/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.com.br/$1 [R,L]
    /*Linha 2: Condiciona que todo acesso vindo da porta 80 será afetado pela regra;*/
    /*Linha 3: Definição da regra, neste caso, sempre utilizar o https:// mesmo quando acessado por http.*/
```

**UPDATE1**

Para apenas 1 dominio:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seudominio\.com [NC] /* aqui é como um if */
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

ou se preferi algo mais claro, mas faz a mesma coisa:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?seudominio.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
```

Se for útil, não esquece de avaliar, isso ajuda muito, abs

Comment: Obrigado, então, eu tenho certificado SSL apenas para 1 domínio, no entanto eu tenho dois domínios no mesmo server e tals.

Por isso a ideia de fazer o redir apenas se o host (entendo eu que seja o www.site.com.br) for o domínio especifico que ativei o SSL, faz sentido?

Se sim, como escrever a rewriteCod?

Comment: Sim, com isso "RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seudominio\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}"